# PIC16f877a switch not reading correctly

Tags: c, switch-statement, pic, mplab

I am having a problem with a switch case when using the UART functions.  I receive data and store it into the eeprom.  I think call a switch statement to see what was sent.  I read the eeprom and the information is right but I am just not able to read the right one.  It always comes base as an error (default case).  I am using Hi-tech C compiler.

```
unsigned char tempVal;
tempVal = eeprom_read(cmdByteAddr);
switch(tempVal){
    //Get temperature
    case 30:
        writeByte('T');
        break;
    //Get temp high
    case 31:
        writeByte('T');
        writeByte('H');
        break;
    //Get temp low
    case 32:
        writeByte('T');
        writeByte('L');
        break;
    //Get humidity
    case 41:
        writeByte('H');
        break;
    //Get humidity high
    case 42:
        writeByte('H');
        writeByte('H');
        break;
    //Get humidity low
    case 43:
        writeByte('H');
        writeByte('L');
        break;
    //Error
    default:
        writeByte('E');
        writeByte(eeprom_read(cmdByteAddr));
        break;
}
```

Comment: So, when you reach the default you do a (pointless) readback from the EEPROM once more, and print the result efter the error indicator 'E'. What gets printed? There's too little information here.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned from `eeprom_read()` is not one of your cases.  The `switch()` is working correctly.  Adjust code to present a more meaningful error using the *same* switch variable and not another call to `eeprom_read()`.

```
default:
    writeByte('E');
    writeByte(tempVal);
    break;  // Not sure why you want `break` here.
```

---

If you still get unsatisfactory results, try `unsigned tempVal`.  Sometimes a compiler get confused, although it should not, on sub-`int` sized data.  You may need to `writeUnsigned(tempVal)` or its equivalent.

You may want to print `cmdByteAddr` also.  Maybe it is outside the EE range.